# How come whenever I run 'gvim' from Terminal in Ubuntu 10.04 Linux, I get a GLib-GObject-CRITICAL gvim error?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gnome, gnome-terminal

When I run gVim from Terminal in Ubuntu 10.04 with Gnome I get this error:

```
(gvim:6226): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion `object->ref_count > 0' failed
```

It looks like that everytime except that the number in between the parans `(gvim: )` is always slightly different. How can I fix this with out having to run

```
gksudo gvim
```

?

which by the way starts gVim with out loading my .vimrc file and which is also annoying because of having to enter the password everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I think the issue was in the blackboard.vim colorscheme I was using. I switched from this version of blackboard.vim

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2280

to this version

http://concisionandconcinnity.blogspot.com/2009/07/vim-part-i-improved-python-syntax.html

Now it works fine without any error.

Answer (score 2):

Since `gksudo gvim` runs gvim as root it will not load the `.vimrc` in your home directory but rather the `.vimrc` in `/root` (if any).

So the problem is either in your `~/.vimrc` or `gksudo` does not redirect the standard error stream.

Unfortunately, versions of gvim that are shipped with Ubuntu for example are known to spew GTK/GLib errors. I use the following alias in `~/.bashrc` to ignore them:

```
alias gvim="gvim $@ &> /dev/null"
```

Comment: Since the Debian/Ubuntu packages don't deviate from upstream at all when it comes to the gui_gtk* source files, this isn't anything specific to Ubuntu's gvim.  It's probably related to the specific version of the glib/gtk libraries that are being used.

Comment: Where in the .bashrc should I place that line?

Comment: @jamessan how would you suggest fixing this? install a different version of glib/gtk? I upgrade in terminal all the time. Not sure what else to do.

Comment: @J3M 7OR3, doesn't matter for the final result, I would place it along with the other alias definitions. Note that you need to login / logout or do `source ~/.bashrc` from your terminal to be able to use the alias.

Answer (score 0):

If it runs as `root` I think the problem is with your `~/.vimrc`. Try `vim -u NONE` and if starts review your `.vimrc`. You may check permissions also.